# Event Registration Error Could not find valid value for id

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I've done a fresh install of WP with CiviCrm as the ONLY plugin.

Is there any solution for the "Could not find valid value for id" problem when using Wordpress 6.4.3 and Civi 5.71.1

Where should I look for url issues.  I do have a cms database base page set as CiviCRM.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: Here's the sequence. Put in the Credit Card, Click REVIEW, Pop-up displays "Pre-Authorizing your card", Page says "CONFIRM Registraion", Click REGISTER, Event Registration Page page ERRORS with "  Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Could not find valid value for id
Return to home page." I do receive the email confirming completed even registration, and I do see the registrant record updated with the event.

Comment: @PradeepNayak Using a page I created on my WP site, I accessed an event using a shortcode of the form

[civicrm component="event" action="register" mode="test" id="N"]

Comment: @PradeepNayak Using a page I created on my WP site, I accessed an event registration transaction using a SHORTCODE of the form

[civicrm component="event" action="register" mode="test" id="N"]

After entering the test credit card info. I CONFIRMED the data entry and then REGISTERED. Result NO ERROR.  

It seems if you use the shortcode to initiate the event payment transaction - it works (at least in test mode). 

Does this lead you to suggest where I might look to fix whatever is wrong so I don't have to have a page dedicated to taking the card payment?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the results of my testing to finally get this working.

For Wordpress - on the Dashboard goto Settings->Permalinks
On my system, the radio button was set on the last item which had /%postname% (NOTE ... and this was the solution) - there was no trailing Slash (/) - so I added the trailing slash and IT WORKS Now.